# How do I find a rogue keyboard shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office-2010

Sometimes, I highlight text in an MS Word document and wish to add a comment about it to send to a co-author.  Following [this official documentation about keyboard shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Word-on-Windows-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#OfficeVersion=2010,_2007) (in the “Review documents” section), I then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> as the keyboard shortcut to insert a comment.  I usually use the modifier keys on the right side of the keyboard because they're close to the <kbd>M</kbd> and I can easily cover all three with the hand that didn't just use the mouse to select that text.  To within human perception time, I often press both modifier keys simultaneously, before the <kbd>M</kbd> (so I don't type an `m`).

However, about half the time, instead of inserting a comment, the highlighted text is *deleted* and replaced with a lowercase mu character (µ).  After years of being unable to figure out the pattern, I have finally found that on the right side of the keyboard, if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key going down first) I get the µ, and if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key going down first), I get the comment.  If I use the modifier keys on the left side of the keyboard, the order doesn't matter and I get the comment either way.

When I right click on the Ribbon and choose "Customize the Ribbon"→"Keyboard Shortcuts,"  I can see that the shortcut to insert a comment is listed as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>:

[image]

Although the modifiers are listed in the wrong order, this matches the [Office documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Word-on-Windows-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#OfficeVersion=2010,_2007).

When I go to the Insert→Symbol→More Symbols dialog, it says the shortcut key assigned to the mu character is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, nothing like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>:

[image]

EDIT (thanks to Jonno for these questions): My Windows keyboard layout is US English.  The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key can be omitted in the <kbd>right-side-Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> combination and I still get the µ character.  However, <kbd>right-side-Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (with or without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) does NOT produce the µ character in other Windows applications such as Notepad, WordPad, Firefox, or Chrome.  Therefore, I am doubting the "system keyboard mapping" theory (thanks Jonno!) that previously seemed promising.

There may have been some time in the past where I needed to type a lot of µ characters, but that time is not the present, and it's annoying to accidentally delete some portion of a document and replace it with an unexpected character, especially after most proofreading checks have taken place and shortly before that document is formally submitted.

Why am I getting µ characters for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (but only with right side modifiers, and not for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>), and how do I get rid of this behavior?

Comment: (1) Look again.  It’s not saying that the shortcut for μ is Alt+X; it’s saying that it is “03BC, Alt+X” — i.e., type “03BC” normally, and then press Alt+X (the shortcut key for converting a two- to five-digit hex number to its corresponding Unicode character; e.g., “40, Alt+X” turns into “@”).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (2) You say, “There may have been some time in the past where I needed to type a lot of µ characters, …” Is it possible that *you* defined this Alt+M shortcut and forgot about it? Try this: (a) exit Word, (b) rename your `Normal.dotm` to a backup, (c) restart Word, and (d) see whether you still have the problem. (3) If you delete the selected text, can’t you get it back with Ctrl+Z?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, according to various online sources (I can't test it as my keyboard hasn't got <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) is the keyboard shortcut, with a lot of keyboard layouts, for the `µ` symbol (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#US-International)).

[image]

In terms of disabling this, one solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229633/how-to-globally-map-altgr-key-to-alt-key) is to add the following registry key, to treat <kbd>AltGr</kbd> as the standard <kbd>Alt</kbd>:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,38,00,38,e0,00,00,00,00
```

Alternately there is software called “SharpKeys” that will set this for you.

One other option is to use the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=22339) to change your keyboard mappings and remove this particular shortcut. Some information on the usage of this can be found [here](http://littletinyfish.com/create-a-new-keyboard-layout-with-the-microsoft-keyboard-layout-creator).

Answer (score 0):

*Heads up: This is still just a partial answer.*

In the “Insert Symbol” dialogue, pressing a keyboard shortcut of interest takes you to the character that would be inserted had you pressed that in the document.  (Here, it works even when putting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key down first.)  This is a helpful tip for tracking down the rogue shortcut.

As it turns out, there is another character called the "Micro Sign" which is visually identical to the Greek Small Letter Mu.  This key has a baked-in assigned shortcut key of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> as well, but if you click on “Shortcut Key…”, it doesn't show up in the (empty) list of keyboard shortcuts:

[image]

Assigning an alternative shortcut causes the new shortcut to appear in place of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> next to "Shortcut key" and in the list of "Current keys" as expected.  Unfortunately, it does not displace the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> "functionality" of inserting µ, and if you remove the new shortcut the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> shortcut key reappears next to "Shortcut key" but not in the list of Current keys (i.e., it's a return to the state shown above).